# Create a Design time task for my user control C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, task, design-time

How to create a custom task for user control?
I know a little about `UITypeEditor` Class and `DesignerAttribute` and I was able to use it to edit properties at run time but what I want to do is similar to this:

[image: editing task during design time]

**A little detail about my question.**

I am after this little arrowhead

[image]

I was able to activate that **Dock in Parent Container** using `DockingAttribute`, the only thing needed is for me to add another functionality like the **Edit Nodes..**
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I would like to create a UI that allows property edit for my usercontrol at design time. like the one found on listboxes, treeviews (like the one presented above; the edit nodes... under treeview tasks) or datagridview, but I have no idea where to start.

my usercontrol is actually a custom treeview (this does not inherit the native treeview).

Comment: This would be a start https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9667/Creating-Custom-Controls-Providing-Design-Time-Sup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found the answer,**

They are called [**Smart Tags**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171830.aspx)

It's my first time making custom user-controls so I'm not really familiar with the terminologies. There were other questions similar to mine so might as well mark this one as duplicate.